# Find the pmf of $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability

> A box has 3 balls numbered from 1 to 3. Two balls are selected randomly and without replacement. Let X denote the number of the first ball and Y denote the number of the second ball. Find the pmf of X and  the pmf of Y.

Thoughts: the random variables look like they have hypergeometric distribution but that wouldn’t fit the experiment properly. For example P(X = 3) would have undefined binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\{X,Y\}$ is a sample of size two, their marginal pmfs are easy:
$$f_X(t)=f_Y(t)=\frac13[1\le t\le 3]$$
where $[.]$ is the Iverson bracket ($1$ if the condition inside is true, $0$ otherwise). This can also be derived from a probability tree.

---

As to the expectation, covariance and correlation, $E(X)=E(Y)=2$ and $E(XY)=\frac{2+3+6}3=\frac{11}3$, so $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)=-\frac13$. $\operatorname{Var}(X)=\operatorname{Var}(Y)=\frac{1+4+9}3-2^2=\frac23$, so $\operatorname{corr}(X,Y)=\frac{-1/3}{2/3}=-\frac12$.

Comment: I solved it like you did but couldn’t calculate E(XY). How did you calculate it?

Comment: @VictorS. It should be easy to see that for $XY$, there's an equal chance of getting $\{1,2\}$, $\{1,3\}$ and $\{2,3\}$ as the drawn numbers - 2, 3 and 6 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You are overthinking this one.  The probability mass function is

$$
P(X,Y) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl} \frac16 & x, y \in \Bbb N \wedge x, y \in [1,3] \wedge x \neq y \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise} \end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: I'm not sure whether the question is asking for the _joint_ pmf (as you show) or the _marginal_ ones.

Comment: It’s the pmf of each. I’ll edit the question

Comment: I’m actually asked to find cov(X, Y) and corr(X, Y) but you can’t do that without the pmf of each (I think). This is why I asked only about the pmfs.

Answer (score 1):

You already have answers. But you expressed interest (elsewhere) in the use of R. So, here is a visualization of the problem via simulation in R:

Take $m = 10^6$ samples of size two without replacement from the box.
Results go into the $2 \times m$ matrix `xy`.  With a million iterations
most results are accurate to two or three places.

```
set.seed(615)    # for reproducibility
m = 10^6;  box=1:3
xy = replicate(m, sample(box, 2))
dim(xy)
[1]       2 1000000
```

Marginal distribution on $X$ has $P(X=1)=P(X=2)=P(X=3)=1/3.$

```
table(xy[1,])/m

       1        2        3 
0.334787 0.332371 0.332842
```

Marginal distribution on $Y$ has $P(Y=1)=P(Y=2)=P(Y=3)=1/3.$

```
table(xy[2,])/m

       1        2        3 
0.332143 0.334202 0.333655
```

You asked only for the marginal distribution, but we have
information about the joint distribution in the simulation. The joint distribution has $\rho = Cor(X,Y) = -1/2.$ Thus $X$ and $Y$
are not independent (as is typical in sampling *without* replacement).

```
cor(xy[1,], xy[2,])
[1] -0.5001037
```

One way to show the joint distribution is to use fewer points
and to 'jitter' them using uniform noise so points will not
plot on top of one another. Each of the six points in the joint
distribution has probability $1/6.$ (Each 'square' consists of about 5000 jittered points.)

```
n = 30000  # fewer points f or figure
X = xy[1,1:n] + runif(n, -.3,.3)
Y = xy[2,1:n] + runif(n, -.3,.3)
plot(X, Y, pch=".")
  abline(v=1:3, col="green2", lwd=2)
  abline(h=1:3, col="green2", lwd=2)
```

[image]

---

*Addendum:* If you are sampleing *with* replacement, the only *code* change is to include the argument `repl=T` in the `sample` function.

```
set.seed(1234)    # for reproducibility
m = 10^6;  box=1:3
xy = replicate(m, sample(box, 2, repl=T))  # <-- CODE CHANGE HERE

table(xy[1,])/m

       1        2        3 
0.333606 0.332602 0.333792    # <-- MARGINALS UNCHANGED
table(xy[2,])/m

       1        2        3 
0.334109 0.332712 0.333179 

cor(xy[1,], xy[2,])
[1] 0.0006655847              # <-- 0 correlation & independent

n = 30000  # fewer points for figure
X = xy[1,1:n] + runif(n, -.3,.3)
Y = xy[2,1:n] + runif(n, -.3,.3)
plot(X, Y, pch=".")
....
```

[image]